# set on hover background colour for button using css id

Tags: html, css, button

hello i am trying to change the background color on hover of my button on my page using its id, i have tried using the id

```
#optinforms-form5-button:hover{
  background-color: white;
  color: black; /* SET COLOR IN BLACK */
}
```

i also tried this

```
input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

but nothing seems to work, this is a screen shot of the button and link to the page where this button is

[image]

at this page  `http://theclosingcode.com/home/

please someone help`

Comment: Check if the selector is correct, also try adding !important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#optinforms-form5-button:hover {
    background: white!important;
    color: black!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The css for the background is inlined, so a simple selector won't work. You have to either remove the inlined css and put in your css file or use !important after the background-color.

Answer (score 0):

The element that you mentioned has inline styling which is higher specificity than any css that you write. I woudn't add important as it's not maintainable and bad practice.

My suggestion would be to remove the inline styling from the element and pass it as a whole from the CSS. This way you would have 1 point of reference and debugging your code.

If this is not possible unfortunately `important!` seems the only way out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the :hover selector to change the style of a button when you move the mouse over it.

Tip: Use the transition-duration property to determine the speed of the "hover" effect:

Example

```
.button {
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
transition-duration: 0.4s;}

.button:hover {
background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
color: white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a separeted CSS file write:

1. `#optinforms-form5-button{ background-color: #current_color;
   color: #current_color; 
   }`
2. `#optinforms-form5-button:hover{ background-color: white; color: black; /* SET COLOR IN BLACK */ }`

Important: As suggested here, it wont work until you remove inline style here in your HTML file:

`<input type="submit" name="submit" id="optinforms-form5-button" value="GET YOUR FREE TRAINING" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#49d0d6">`

I strongly recommend you to separete CSS and HTML